# How to draw horizontal percentage chart in Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts

I want to draw a horizontal percentage chart like the attached picture. I already try some library but can't found solution. Please help me!

[image]

Comment: Which libraries did you use? and where you get stuck? Post your code

Answer (score 0):

It is called "Stacked bar charts". Google chart provides it:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#stacked-bar-charts

Comment: Thank for your response, but it doesn't look like my requirement, my chart is just a pie chart but in horizontal form.

Comment: pie chart is a collection of pieces  to make a circle 360 degrees. Now to make it horizontal, you map your range [0 degree, 360 degrees] to range [0%, 100%]. Bring that data to "stacked bar chart" with 1 bar only, you will have your horizontal bar. You can configure it to hide axises :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stacked progress bar feature of drupal:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

Go to the bottom to read about it. It's simple to use and you can customize the colors with css.